What is the best function/stage to use tokenizer in Pytorch's data processing?
I am subclassing torch.utils.data.Dataset and writing a collate function to be passed to Dataloader's dataset and collate_fn argument respectively.
Between Dataset's __getitem__ or collate_fn I was wondering what would be the best function to use tokenizer (huggingface's FastTokenizer) in (or is there another better option out of these two that I don't know of?)
collate_fn seems to me as the best option since I can use tokenizer to tokenize and adding padding for the full batch together, which should also help with tokenization speed. But I am not sure if it can cause any problems, in future if not now as some of my teammates start using/customizing my code.

What is your question? function and stage are different meaning.

It is more efficient applying it on the collate_fn as the tokenizer accepts a list of texts (the batch), specially if the sequences need to be padded at a fixed length, you would be processing batch-wise

I don't think this is true. The tokenizer would then be running in the main thread, no? I think you want to call it in your data loader.

Neither. You want to tokenize your entire dataset in batch prior to training. Tokenizing during training slows it down, and is wasteful if you're doing multiple epochs (you will tokenize the same items multiple times).
You should tokenize your entire dataset first. Then do batching and padding in your collate function.
It sounds like you're using huggingface tokenizers - you should also use huggingface datasets and the collate functions they provide.

that depends a lot on what you want to achieve, if you are augmenting your texts replacing words by synonyms you need to apply tokenization on the fly, also if you have huge datasets you cannot map the tokenizer, you have to do it on the fly

How does dataset size prevent mapping the tokenizer? It's pretty standard to use Apache Arrow (or libraries like datasets, built on Arrow) to process datasets that are too large to fit into memory (which is the norm with modern NLP). Data augmentation can be pre-generated. Tokenizing on the fly will tank your GPU utilization and make training substantially slower for no real benefit.

Prefetching batches during training avoids GPU utilization issues when tokenizing or applying any kind of preprocessing on the fly. If you have huge amounts of data, which most of the time is stored in the cloud (tends to be the cheapest option), you have most of the times to stream it and tokenize on the fly, same when you have limited amount of resources like disk space

@Karl I agree that pre-tokenizing the data is the best option when it comes to the training efficiency. That said, I do not have a lot of data for my task and I am still experimenting on what features go in as tokens. So it is easier for me to just do the tokenization on the fly for now.
